# free editable treeview control in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want a free editable Treeview in ASP.NET MVC with context menu. Is any Treeview control available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use jstree for your requirement.There is a lot of possibilities.

documentation is available in http://www.jstree.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [`jqTree`](http://mbraak.github.com/jqTree/) plugin which has the [`tree.contextmenu`](http://mbraak.github.com/jqTree/#event-tree-contextmenu) event triggered when a user right clicks on a node allowing you to provide custom interface.

Comment: Thank you for your valueable reply. I trying to create treeview using jqTree. But i found a negative vote in your answer.I try to jqTree with ASP.NET MVC is not possible?

Comment: Of course that it is possible. `jqTree` is a client side, javascript based control. You could use it alongside with any server side framework such as PHP, Java Servlets, ASP.NET, ...